# $hour returning undefined in MongoDB "aggregate"

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have documents in a collection. Some of them have elements like this:

```
"arrivalTime": {
    "$date": "2020-02-03T20:19:00.000Z"
},
```

I'm trying to group these documents by the hour of arrivalTime. (Note that not all documents have an arrivalTime, so some of these will be grouped into a 'null' group.) But when I try this:

```
myCollection.aggregate([
 { "$group": {
        "_id": {
             "arrivalhour": { "$hour": "$arrivalTime"}
        }, 

        "recordcount": {"$sum":1} 
}], function(err, docs){
console.log(docs);
}
```

...it's just returning 'undefined' for all the values of arrivalhour. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks fine: https://mongoplayground.net/p/GVuGHi329nt, any additional details ?

Comment: `"2020-02-03T20:19:00.000Z"` is string, not a `Date` object. Convert the string to Date with [$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/index.html) or [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) then you can use `$hour`

Comment: @mickl That's odd, trying to figure out what the difference is here...

Comment: I figured it out. I had some old entries in 'documents' that were messing it up. I fixed those and now it works. I wonder if I should delete this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it's work for me

```
myCollection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      'hour': {
        '$hour': {
          date: '$arrivalTime', //your db time date
          //timezone: "+0530"  //pass the time zone 
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        arrivalhour: '$hour'
      },
      "recordcount": { "$sum": 1 }
    }
  }
]), function (err, docs) {
  console.log(docs);
}
```